# Transfer photos from iPhone - DCIM mount gone but Documents remains

Tags: mount, nautilus, configuration, iphone

iPhone connected via USB to Ubuntu 22.04.  Initially "straight out of the box", TWO mounts correctly appeared immediately in Nautilus: (1) DCIM images and (2) for Documents arranged by App. Successfully transferred a selection of images to the PC from the iPhone.  But the iPhone is full and in need of concerted number of sessions to get the images off.

But on subsequent connection, only Document shows and is browsable. The DCIM mount is no longer there.  Have tried various ways to reset the "trusted" connection between the iPhone and the PC but no joy. Strangely, rapid photo downloader can see the photos but there are too many to downloads in one hit.

I would like to start afresh on the PC by resetting the connection and starting over.  I have looked for iFuse config files under my Home folder tree but see nothing I can delete.  Can someone suggest a setting file elsewhere for this connection that I can delete or edit.  Possibly in Nautilus?

Answer (score -1):

Try unplugging then re-plugging in the phone three times.  If you still don't get the DCIM folder:

1. At a command prompt issue the following:
   sudo usbmuxd -f -v
   If it says already running, it will provide a number use that number in a kill command:   kill -9 [that number]
2. now do the command again (sudo usbmuxd -f -v

Comment: No that did not work.